# What's the smallest rank matroid in which a given collection of sets are all closed?

Tags: combinatorics, matroids

Let us suppose we have a finite ground set $E$ and a collection of sets $S_1, \ldots, S_m$ which we can assume without losing much generality is closed under intersection and we can
similarly assume that $S_1=E$.

There are matroids on the set $E$ such that all of these sets are closed (in particular, in the free matroid every set is closed). As such there is such a matroid of minimal rank.

As a lower bound, if there are $k+1$ of the sets forming a chain, then since closed sets are maximal for their rank, they all have different rank, so the rank of $E$ is at least $k$.

Is this lower bound ever not attained, ie is there some intersection-closed family $F$ of subsets of a ground set $E$ (with $E\in F$) with no chain of length $k+2$, but such that any matroid on $E$ for which all subsets in $F$ are closed has rank at least $k+1$?

Comment: thanks @joriki, have edited

Comment: Why can we assume $S_1=E$? If we didn't assume this, the family of all subsets except $E$ itself would be a counterexample (with chains up to length $|E|$, but the only matroid that makes all sets closed would be the free matroid, which has rank $|E|$).

Comment: I mean "given any family $F$ of sets, there is a family $F'$ of sets containing $E$ and being closed under intersection such that in any matroid all elements of $F$ are closed if and only if all elements of $F'$ are closed"